# What is a good place for people who recently decided to get serious in photography to get started learning?

Tags: learning, photography-basics, education

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start learning photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-start-learning-photography)

I recently bought a ILC, and it has prompted me to scour the internet for resources that help me use the camera better, take better pictures. So far I've found [short course to using your digital cameras](http://www.shortcourses.com/use/) as a good source for getting started in photography. Do you have any other recommendations for people who are new to photography? (feel free to recommend sites on image-processing software for editing pictures as well)

Comment: As you take pictures with problem you identify, ask questions here about the specific examples and we can talk about how you might improve them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this question has already been asked.  Here are some.  I will add these to the tag wikis

[What are good resources for a beginning photographer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/what-are-good-resources-for-a-beginning-photographer)

[How to start learning photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-start-learning-photography)

[What are the first few photography books someone should read?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-are-the-first-few-photography-books-someone-should-read)

[What blogs should I be following if I am learning photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-blogs-should-i-be-following-if-i-am-learning-photography)

[What are the best online photo classes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1928/what-are-the-best-online-photo-classes)

[I know the basic technical stuff, what now?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20884/i-know-the-basic-technical-stuff-what-now)

Comment: can you recommend a few sites/books on beginning photo editing. What are the first few sites/book someone should read for photo editing? (I don't think there's currently a wiki for that right now) Thanks!

Comment: Also search for ' understanding shutter speed, iso, and aperture ' in Google . It will point to some great articles

Answer (score 2):

One of the most important things, in my opinion, is to **take a lot of pictures.** By this, I don't mean go out and take 500 pictures of the same thing - but to take pictures of different things, at different angles, using resources you can find on the internet. (I'm not planning on posting any, as MikeW gave quite a few, and a quick [Google search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=beginner%20photography%20tutorials) should lead to more, not to mention the [Digital Photography School](http://digital-photography-school.com/).)

Try bringing your camera with you wherever you go. All the reading and learning you do, will do absolutely no good if you don't apply the knowledge and get creative. Remember, if your camera is at home in the bag **it does no good.**